# Convert NSDictionary to Swift Dictionary

Tags: dictionary, swift, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

Now I know that when swift compiles it just makes a NSDictionary, but the NSDictionary and Swift dictionaries have different syntax.  Is there a way (through a loop or something) to convert a NSDictionary to a swift dictionary of the same type for `<key, value>`?

OR

Is there a way to convert this to a Swift dictionary instead of NSDictionary?

```
let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &error) as NSDictionary
```

Comment: under the hood the _Swift_ `Dictionary` is literally an _Obj-C_ `NSMutableDictionary`, you can bridge them toll-free.

Answer (score 28):

use:

```
let jsonDic = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>;
```

Comment: For some reason, that didn't work for me. What worked for me was `let b = d as [NSObject:AnyObject]`

Comment: For SWIFT 3 you can use JSONSerialization.

Answer (score 4):

I found answer from http://www.swift-studies.com/blog/2014/6/6/loading-a-swift-dictionary-from-a-plist-file

```
var swiftDict : Dictionary<String,AnyObject!> = Dictionary<String,AnyObject!>()
for key : AnyObject in ocDictionary.allKeys {
    let stringKey = key as String 
    if let keyValue = ocDictionary.valueForKey(stringKey){
        swiftDict[stringKey] = keyValue
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe in some very specific cases that may pay off, but I don't think that the overhead in memory, cpu and battery use of making a shallow copy of the NSDictionary has any real advantage. Since you can use an NSDictionary as a regular Dictionary the difference is almost non existent.

Answer (score 3):

`NSDictionary` and `Dictionary` are pretty much interchangeable. So there's no need to, but yes you can:

```
let jsonDict = (NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &error) as NSDictionary) as Dictionary
```

Comment: Are they what? Interchangeable with their counterparts? Yes.

Comment: I keep having to type out `as NSString` everywhere though and ti doesn't like `as String`. Maybe this is because I'm defining `jsonDict : [[String:AnyObject]]`?

Comment: I believe it is, when going from AnyObject to anything, you have to cast it.

Comment: Beware bridging if NSDictionary to Dictionary is not toll free.