# How to get NSDictionary from NSDictionary in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I am new in Swift.My json detail below.How to get dictionary of 'assdata' from AP0 Dictionary.Please detail briefly and step by step.

```
"AP0": {
"assdata": "{
            \"Description\":\"Test\",
            \"Service Requested\":\" Equipment\",
            \"Requested For\":\"Chandan\",
            \"Requested Location\":\"\\\\Locations\\\\SBCBSC\\\\ SBCBSC - MAIN\",
            \"Requested By\":\"Chandan\",
            \"Request Id\":\"100067809074\",
             \"datastatus\":\"true\"}",
"Linked Form": "Equipment",
"System Record ID": "17213450626",
"Submitted By": "Chandan",
"Linked Business Object": "Request",
"Linked Record": "100067809074-0",
"datastatus": "true"
}
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert NSDictionary to Swift Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569447/convert-nsdictionary-to-swift-dictionary)

Comment: In which variable you stored this response and where? Show that part of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
let myJSON =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

            let keys = myJSON.allKeys
            print(keys)

            let values = myJSON.allValues
            print(values)

            let dict = values[2]
            print(dict)

            let dictAssdata = dict["assdata"]
            print(dictAssdata)
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: for i in 0..<values.count{
                       let dict = values[i]
                        
                        let dictAssdata = dict["assdata"]
                        print(dictAssdata)
                        }

Answer (score 1):

Your key `assdata` contains String JSON response so that for getting Dictionary from it you need to convert it to first data.

```
if let jsonStr = yourResponse["assdata"] as? String {
    if let data = jsonStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        do {
             let dic = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
        } catch let error as NSError {
             print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not enter into first if condition

Comment: Chandan - there is no loop.

Comment: @ChandanJee Can you show your json parsing code that will more halpful.

Comment: if let data = data {do { if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
          print("jsonResult = \(jsonResult)")
                        if let jsonStr = jsonResult["assdata"] as? String {
                            if let data = jsonStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {do {
 let dic = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]} catch let error as NSError { print(error) } }}} } catch let error as NSError { print(error.localizedDescription) }}

Comment: Check it @Mr.Nirav D